# how to fill page with empty rows or get the distance from the node to the bottom of the page?

Tags: xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

[image]

The amount of data is uncertain and the height of each piece of data is also uncertain.When a page is left over, I want the remaining pages to be filled with tables as well.How to do it with xsl-fo？please

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.1"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
        xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java" 
        xmlns:jfn="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java/cn.net.jully.common.util.JullyXslUtil"
        exclude-result-prefixes="fo java jfn">
        <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />`enter code here`
        <xsl:include href="../include/common.xsl" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `transparent` as the color of the borders for your table.
2. In the `fo:static-content` for the region-before, make an empty table of the correct size and in the correct position to appear to be the table for the data.

This assumes that the table column widths are fixed.  If you are using automatic table layout, then the formatter will work out the widths of the columns and you won't know what widths to use in your background table.

Comment: Thank you very much. But if there is too much data, we need pagination.And the actual situation is that there is another table and other display information this table.So I don’t know the position and size of this table. So is there a more general way to deal with more complicated situations?Thanks again.

Comment: If the second table uses the same column widths, you may be able to generate an area between the two tables that covers over the borders from the background. However, that would be a hack on top of a hack. Can you add a sample of your current XSL-FO to your question, and also indicate which formatter you are using, so that we can better see what you are working with.

Comment: I calculated the approximate length based on the amount of data, then set the fixed height for the table.it work